# steering behavior and passed time

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I'm trying to implement steering behaviors but I have a problem with "including" the passed time in the calculation and then allowing me to control the speed of the game. I have seen various sources of steering behaviors and I've come up with this (Arrive behavior):

```
var toTarget:Vector2D = new Vector2D( mEntity.targetPosition.x, mEntity.targetPosition.y );
toTarget.subtract( mEntity.position );
var dist:Number = toTarget.length;
toTarget.normalize().scale( mEntity.maxSpeed );
if( dist < slowDownDist ) {
    toTarget.scale( dist / slowDownDist );
}
return toTarget.subtract( mEntity.velocity );
```

And here's the *advanceTime* method of MovingEntity:

```
var steeringForce:Vector2D = mSteering.calculate();
steeringForce.x /= mMass;
steeringForce.y /= mMass;
steeringForce.scale( time );
mVelocity.x += steeringForce.x;
mVelocity.y += steeringForce.y;
x += mVelocity.x * time;
y += mVelocity.y * time;
```

The steering force should be (at some point) directly opposite to the entity's velocity and thus making it stop. The problem I see and do not understand is that in order to simulate acceleration the force needs to be divided by mass and also to consider the passed time it needs to be multiplied by that time - but this scales the steering force down a lot and causes the entity to overshoot the target spot instead of stopping there so then it returns back which effectively causes oscillation. If I do not multiply the force with the time then the moving entity behaves slightly differently depending on the game speed.

Answer (score 1):

By second (?) Newton's law **`F = m * a`** where `F` is force, `m` is mass and `a` is acceleration. Force is measured in newtons, mass in kilograms and acceleration in meters per second per second. So, you just need to apply bigger force, and lave the calculation as is.